# Content-Security-Policy htaccess block all iframes but one

Tags: .htaccess, security, iframe

My objective is to block my site from being accessed in an iFrame, with the exception of defend.net. I'm able to successfully do it with this line:

`Header append X-Frame-Options: "ALLOW-FROM https://*.defend.net/"`

However, I read that that's been depreciated.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    Header add Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self'  'https://*.defend.net';"      
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
</IfModule>
```

What is the most effective, secure way I can achieve my objective?
Can I safely remove this and have the same protection?

```
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with that seems to work as intended:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self'  https://www.google.com https://www.youtube.com; frame-ancestors 'self'  https://*.defend.net;"
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
</IfModule>
```